# NFC Card/Tag with RSA/ECC

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, mifare

I'm looking for a type (model) of NFC tag/card that would be capable of communicating with Android device and do the following:

1. Receive a data message
2. Sign or encrypt it with a secret key stored on the card
3. Send the signed/encrypted data back to the device.
4. In addition, the card should be able to return the open key by a
   request

Is there any NXP or other chip capable of doing the task?

Comment: Could you please react to answers on your questions spoonboy? I can see you have [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268123/how-enclosed-import-works-in-python)  open too, please read the FAQ on how you can accept answers. You can vote them up as well.

Comment: Note, that encrypting data is a public key operation. While some cards support that also, nearly nobody uses it, since it is faster to do it on the host side and there is no security gain, since only the public key is involved. Point 1 to 3 are in fact jusr one Perform Security Operation command (ISO 7816-8) if the hash is computed outside the card. With the "open" key of 4. you refer to that public key?

Comment: Yes, the card should be able to send back the open key so that it would be possible to valide the responce immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NXP chips J3A041, J3A081, J3D081 etc. will probably fit your requirements. As well as chips from other vendors like AT90SC20818RCFV, SLE77CLFX2400PM, S3CT9KA, SA23YR18, M7794  etc.

Will you develop your own OS for this? Looks more practical to use a solutions like JCOP, CONVEGO Join, JK21 etc. to use Java Card for card side development.

If you would like to concentrate efforts just on Android side - a ready tag like [NFCCipher](http://nfccipher.com) may work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The NXP SmartMX line of chips that sport an asymmetric co-processor should be able to do that. If you want to design your own protocol then a Java Card solution (like JCOP on NXP) should do the trick. Signature generation is generally available on higher end processor models, but there should be plenty choice between those.